# go install @latest found but does not contain package

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I'm trying to install my package using `go install` but I get this error message when running the command `go install github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd/gcloc@latest`:

```
go install: github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd/gcloc@latest: module github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc@latest found (v1.0.0), but does not contain package github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd/gcloc
```

I want the executable name to be `gcloc`.

Here is the current source code: https://github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc

Note: I've already tried `go clean -modcache` but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

As the main function of this package isn't on its root, you should pass the directory of the `main` package on your command.

So, your command will be:
 `go install -v github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd@latest`

Comment: But in this way, the executable name will be `cmd` and I want it to be `gcloc`

Comment: Currently has a [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44469) in GitHub that references this problem, but isn't implemented or also accepted as a proposal.

So, what I recommend is to you create a sub-folder inside cmd folder, and name it as `gcloc`

Comment: But thats what I have on my workspace, there is a sub-folder inside cmd named `gcloc` with a `main.go` file and I cant install using `go install github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd/gcloc@latest`, or if I install with `go install -v github.com/JoaoDanielRufino/gcloc/cmd@latest` the binary name is `cmd`

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue when I was trying to use go install to install the cloudflare/cf-terraforming tool on my machine. The documentation for this tool is not clear on the installation and I had to dig around to get this to work

Basically @Jictyvoo answer above sums it up, if the path is pointing to anything other than directory where the main.go file is sitting I got the error

**Command**: `go install github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming@latest v0.8.0@latest`

> go: github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming@latest: module
> github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming@latest found (v0.8.0), but does not
> contain package github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming

when I switched to the below it worked fine for me:
**Command**: `go install -v github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming/cmd/cf-terraforming@latest`

This worked for me after checking the repo and realising that the main.go file was sitting in the cmd/cf-terraforming subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue like you did when I install "golang.org/x/mobile" , i click it from browser and jump to `https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile` , i try to every command I can , but is not work apparently.

by the way ,the env of my localhost have that  GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

the go.mod can import and download the same resource , but when I use "go install ", something is wrong

Comment: and when I use go install  the specific command is " go install -v golang.org/x/mobile@latest "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).